# What does ''Reduced Coordination Airspace'' mean?

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology, easa

What does ''Reduced Coordination Airspace'' mean?
There is a definition in [here](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/204.pdf), page 4 bottom image.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your title is in question form. Yet, you answer your own question in the rest of your post without an explanation of your confusion or what/why you are asking.

Comment: I didn't get the definition exactly; I think it is not detailed so much,  My question is clear what is the Reduced Coordination Airspace' with an one example may be. @Dean F.

Comment: Please quote the specific material you want help with, and name the source, in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 5):

In many parts of the world, the military has reserved large parts of airspace for military activities. As a rule of thumb, civilian traffic is not permitted in these areas. Traditionally, such military areas were reserved 24/7, regardless of whethere there actually was any military activity at a given time. This is not very efficient, as it forces civilian flights to make, sometimes long, detours to avoid military airspace, even when the military isn't actively using those areas.

In Europe, the concept of "Flexible Use of Airspace" has been a way to try to reduce these unnecessary detours, in an effort to shorten flight tracks, reduce flight times and fuel burnt for civilian flights. One way to do this is to allow ATC to coordinate civilian flights through military areas (temporary segregated areas) when possible.

Reduced Coordination Airspace takes this one step further, essentially allowing civilian flights to operate within military airspace when there is little or no military activity, without requiring ATC to coordinate individual flights with the military. It basically allows ATC to give shortcuts to civilian flights, taking them through military areas, without having to ask the military for permission for every single flight, thus contributing to a more flexible use of airspace.

The actual definition, from the document you included in the question, is as follows:

> Specified portion of airspace implemented when Operational AirTraffic (OAT) is light or has ceased and within which General AirTraffic (GAT) is permitted to operate outside the ATS route structurewithout requiring General Air Traffic (GAT) controllers to initiate coordination with Operational Air Traffic (OAT) controllers.